# Duplicate values when using express and socket.io in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a nodeJS application using express and socket.io. I would like to osolate some code so that it only runs on one page that I serve. To do this I have used express to listen to the request and feed a html page as a response.

```
app.get('/archive', function(request, response) {
    response.sendfile(__dirname + "/views/table.html");
}
```

I also have a socket.io function that listens and sends the data to the html page.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
     channel.subscribe('cheat', function(message) {
      socket.emit('message', message);
});\
```

Everything runs great when the code is like this but as soon as I try and put the socket.on function inside the app.get function I have issues. The first request works perfectly but when the page is refresh all the data gets duplicated. The first time it is x2 then x3 then x4 and so on. Does anyone know why this is happening?

This is what my final code looks like:

```
app.get('/archive', function(request, response) {
    response.sendfile(__dirname + "/views/table.html");
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        channel.subscribe('cheat', function(message) {
        socket.emit('message', message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the url.parse function to get the name of the page like so:

```
var curURL = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
```

Then I can check the current URL

```
 if (curURL == '/') {
    //code
}
```

As for the problem with duplicate values, I forgot to unsubscribe on exit. After subscription.unsubscribe(); it all works.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put a Socket.IO connection listener inside a HTTP route. The `connection` event for the Socket.IO object is called each time there is a connection, so if you make a new connection listener each time the HTTP route is called, then you will have duplicate listeners which will all fire when there is a connection.

If you don't want Socket.IO on a certain page, don't include the client script on that page. Otherwise, an alternative method to do this is to store the client path in a cookie, and access that cookie during authorization. Then you can accept or deny the client.

Comment: When I use socket.handshake.url I get a unique URL (/socket.io/1/?t=128438943) not the /path

Comment: Sorry, that appears to have been incorrect. I've amended the answer.